# Logarithmic Plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

Consider the following :

```
daList={{1., 588.956}, {2.15443, 581.347}, {4.64159, 573.648}, 
        {10.,560.676}, {21.5443, 552.881}, {46.4159, 547.851}, 
        {100.,544.908}, {215.443, 543.407}, {464.159, 542.358}, 
        {1000., 541.452}}


ListPlot[daList, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]
```

[image]

How could I get each points to be equally spaced along the x axis. I guess a logarithmic Range?

Comment: I am removing the mathematica-8 tag, because this is not restricted or specific to version 8.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I used the tag so solutions could take it into account.

Comment: I see.  I think it makes more sense to use the [mathematica-8] tag to pertain to features that are specifically v8 related.  You can reasonably assume that most people (except me) are using the current version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `ListLogLinearPlot[daList]` which produces

[image: ListLogLinearPlot]

Answer (score 6):

Heike has given you a simple answer (and the best answer) that suits your needs. To answer your specific question of doing it in `ListPlot`, here's a simple example:

```
Clear@tickFun
tickFun[min_, max_] := 
  Table[{i, 10^i, {.02, 0}}, {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max]}];
ListPlot[{Log10@#1, #2} & @@@ daList, Ticks -> {tickFun, Automatic}]
```

[image]